# Backup copy of fstab on Dropbox

Tags: command-line, 18.04, files, icons, dropbox

For security reasons I want to keep a copy of ~/etc/fstab on Dropbox.

In terminal, I executed the following command:

```
sudo cp /etc/fstab ~/Dropbox/fstab.bak -p
```

This copied the file to the local folder which syncs with Dropbox.

However, the icon for the file in Dropbox shows it as locked and with an X

[image]

and the file does not appear in the files list on the Dropbox website for my account.

I can however open the file with emacs in the local Dropbox folder.

Has this file file actually been uploaded to the cloud and if not how can I achieve this?

Comment: Try changing the ownership of `fstab.bak` . Let it be owned by you instead of root.

Comment: In other words, do not use `sudo` for the copy. Then the copy will immediately be owned by you as user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, Dropbox does only upload files that are owned by you, even if the file is readable by all users. To make sure the file makes it to Dropbox, ensure it is owned by yourself.

It suffices to issue your copy command without `sudo`, i.e.

```
cp /etc/fstab ~/Dropbox/fstab.bak -p
```

A copy of a file to which you have read access, is owned by the one making the copy.

You could change the ownership of your existing file with the command

```
sudo chown $USER:$USER ~/Dropbox/fstab.bak
```

Immediately after executing the command, Dropbox will refresh and this time transfer it to the cloud.

Comment: That worked... thanks. Thought sudo was required but obviously not.